# (_, integerLiteralConvertible) is not convertible to integerliteralconvertible

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring

I am using stringByReplacingCharactersInRange and always receive the above error message. Here is my code:

```
var detailTextFinal = detailText as NSString
if detailTextFinal.rangeOfString("start").location != NSNotFound {
let endSpan = detailTextFinal.rangeOfString("end")
detailTextFinal = detailTextFinal.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, endSpan.location + 6), withString: "")
            }
```

By the way, detailText is a String.
I have attempted to typecast back and forth from NSString to String. Somehow it does not work.

Comment: What is `stringBetween` ??

Comment: Good question. My bad. Fixed the code and replaced detailText.stringBetween with detailTextFinal.

Comment: Your updated code compiles without problems for me.

Comment: Then it could be my xCode that is corrupt? Bummer - Even clean does not work. The odd thing is that very similar code works in another part of my program?!

Comment: Really odd... I deleted the code and wrote it again the same way. Now it works! Thanks Martin R for compiling and giving me the hint.